# Can Web Application Retrieve Data from Firebase Database using C#?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Android mobile application that used to upload image and text to Firebase Database. Now, I have another web application that using C#, this is used to retrieve the data (which uploaded by the mobile app) from the Firebase. I found some examples regarding on how to retrieve data using C#, but it needs to "Add Firebase to your Web App" . Is it possible that not adding web app? Thank you.

I mean, is it possible that my mobile and web applications use the same Firebase Database/Storage, and both applications can add, edit, delete the data in the same Firebase Database/Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have an ios and web application using the same realtime database and same storage.

From the firebase docs:

> The Firebase Realtime Database is a cloud-hosted database. Data is stored as JSON and synchronized in realtime to every connected client. When you build cross-platform apps with our iOS, Android, and JavaScript SDKs, all of your clients share one Realtime Database instance and automatically receive updates with the newest data.

To add web or ios to the project, you need to go to the firebase console and then click on add another app and choose if ios/android/web and just follow the steps.